# Find the least squares estimator of the parameter B (beta) in the following regression model: y= B + u What is the variance of the estimator?

Tags: least-squares, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Find the least squares estimator of the parameter B (beta) in the following regression model: y= B + u
What is the variance of the estimator?

Comment: (-1) $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i/n$. $\sum_{i=1}^n \left(Y_i - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i/n\right)^2/n$. You're welcome. :)

Comment: What changes if the regression model line is y=bx + u?